# How do I write php in .php file that is rendered to the viewable webpage

Tags: php, html, syntax, comments

I'm trying to write a basic example of php that I want to be viewed on my website. In other words I want the following code to be viewable but I would also like a copy of it to be executable on the webpage:

```
<body>
    <p>
      <?php
      $food = array("Bananas", "Toast", "Eggs", "Bacon");
      echo "I like " . $food[0] . ", " . $food[1] . 
               " and " . $food[2] . " and " . $food[3] . "."; 
      ?>
   </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Just place the same code without the `<?php ?>` tags around it above your code.

Comment: `<?php` and `?>` makes code inside to execute, use `&lt;?php` and `?&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php` and `?>` makes code inside to execute, use `&lt;?php` and `?&gt;`